# Program that counting down by 10, 5, and 1

Tags: c#

I have the following code, the program supposed to count down by ten until 30, after that by 5 until 10 and the count down by 1. It's work fine counting by ten, but never reach `Decrement(ref remainingTime, 5);`I am new to programming, any hint is welcomed. Thank you!

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
        
  int initialTime = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
  
  int remainingTime = initialTime;
  while (remainingTime > 0)
  { 
    
    if (remainingTime > 30)
    {
      Decrement(ref remainingTime, 10);
      break;
    }

    if (remainingTime > 10)
    {
      Decrement(ref remainingTime, 5);
      break;
    }

    Decrement(ref remainingTime);
    break;

  }
  
  Console.Write("0\n");
  Console.Read();
}

static void Decrement(ref int baseValue, int step = 1)
{
  for (int i = baseValue; i >= 0; i -= step)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(i);
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you think `break` does?

Comment: I've tried with continue, but the counting never stops

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a good start, however, you are missing few key points here.

1. You don not need a *for* loop inside your *Decrement* function. You have created nested loops which is not required.
2. Also, you are counting till zero inside your for loop, hence *baseValue* will always be zero when it comes out of *Decrement* function.
3. There is no need to break from your *while* loop. Unless someone enters a negative value.
4. Use *else if* instead of *if*

Look at this code -

```
static void Main1(string[] args)
{

    int initialTime = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    int remainingTime = initialTime;
    while (remainingTime > 0)
    {

        if (remainingTime > 30)
        {
            Decrement(ref remainingTime, 10);
        }
        else if (remainingTime > 10)
        {
            Decrement(ref remainingTime, 5);
        }
        else
        {
            Decrement(ref remainingTime);
        }

    }

    Console.Write("0\n");
    Console.Read();

}

static void Decrement(ref int baseValue, int step = 1)
{
  baseValue -= step;
  Console.WriteLine(baseValue);
}
```

Also, add a negative value condition to this code.

Answer (score 1):

You should delete `break` statement after `Decrement` call in `if` statement

Your code never reach `Decrement(ref remainingTime, 5);` because you have `break` statement in `if (remainingTime > 30)` condition body. It stops your loop and code goes further, already outside the loop.

I'd advise you to learn how to use the debugger. This is a very good skill.

```
           static void Main(string[] args)
       {
       
           int initialTime = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
   
           int remainingTime = initialTime;
           while (remainingTime > 0)
           { 
   
               if (remainingTime > 30)
               {
                   Decrement(ref remainingTime, 10);
               }
   
   
               if (remainingTime > 10)
               {
                   Decrement(ref remainingTime, 5);
               }
   
               Decrement(ref remainingTime);
               break;
   
           }
   
           Console.Write("0\n");
           Console.Read()
       }
   
       static void Decrement(ref int baseValue, int step = 1)
       {

           for (int i = baseValue; i >= 0; i -= step)
           {
               Console.WriteLine(i);
           }
       }
```

Comment: I've tried, but after that the loop never end

Comment: I updated the code in my answer, try it. It works.

Comment: It doesn't end because you have `console.read()` delete it or press enter when the output ends

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using *enumeration*: given `baseValue` we return *sequence* `IEnumerable<int>`:

```
  public static IEnumerable<int> Decrement(int baseValue) {
    for (int value = baseValue; value > 0; ) {
      if (value > 30)
        value -= 10;
      else if (value > 10)
        value -= 5;
      else
        value -= 1;

      yield return value;   
    } 
  }
```

Then you can put

```
  static void Main(string[] args) {
    int initialTime = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    // Having enumeration, we can enumerate its items:
    foreach (var time in Decrement(initialTime)) 
      Console.WriteLine(time);

    Console.Write("0\n");
    Console.Read();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to break the problem up into individual loops. There's no reason that it needs to be one loop:

```cs
static void main()
{
  int initialTime = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

  int remainingTime = initialTime;

  while (remainingTime > 30 )
  {
      Console.WriteLine(remainingTime);
      remainingTime -= 10;
  }

  while (remainingTime > 10 )
  {
      Console.WriteLine(remainingTime);
      remainingTime -= 5;
  }

  while (remainingTime > 0 )
  {
      Console.WriteLine(remainingTime);
      remainingTime -= 1;
  }

  Console.WriteLine(remainingTime);

}
```

However, having done that, you might notice that each of those loops looks... rather similar. You might notice that the only thing that changes is the terminating bound (30, 10, 0), and the decrement amount (10, 5, 1).

You can *refactor* it to remove the duplication in a couple of ways.

- You could extract the loop into a shared method, thus:

  ```cs
  static void main()
  {
    int initialTime = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    int remainingTime;

    remainingTime = countDown( initialTime, 10, 30 ) ;
    remainingTime = countDown( initialTime,  5, 10 ) ;
    remainingTime = countDown( initialTime,  1,  0 ) ;

    Console.WriteLine(remainingTime);

  }

  static int countDown( int time, int step, int bound )
  {
    while ( time > step )
    {
      Console.WriteLine(time);
      time -= step;
    }
    return time;
  }
  ```
- You could collapse it to a single loop, thus:

  ```cs
  static void main()
  {
    int initialTime = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    int remainingTime = initialTime;
    while ( remainingTime > 0 )
    {
      int step = remainingTime > 30 ? 10
               : remainingTime > 10 ?  5
               :                       1
               ;
      Console.WriteLine(remainingTime);
      remainingTime -= step; 
    }

    Console.WriteLine(remainingTime);

  }
  ```